# Deconstructing values nextjs: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'XXX' before initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, next.js

I am using Apollo Client with Nextjs and would like to deconstruct values for easier reading.

I am trying to do this insisde `pages/index.js`

```js
import { useQuery } from '~/lib/apollo'
return {
    const { data: { allAwards = []} = {} } = useQuery(allAwards) //ReferenceError: Cannot access 'allAwards' before initialization
    .....
}
```

## lib/apollo

```
export const useQuery = function(query) {
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar()
  const { options = {} } = sortParams([...arguments])
  const { loading, data: queryData, error, refetch } = HookQuery(query, {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    ...options,
  })
  let transformData = {}
  if (queryData) transformData = new ApolloClass(queryData).start()
  if (error && !options.noError) hookLogger(enqueueSnackbar, error)
  return {
    queryData,
    error,
    loading,
    data: transformData,
    refetch,
  }
}
```

## data

```
{
  data: {
   allAwards: []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using destructuring assignment to declare a variable named `allAwards` from the value returned by the `useQuery` hook -- and then you try to pass that same variable to the hook. As the error indicates, you can't use a variable before its declared.

```
const { data: { allAwards = []} = {} } = useQuery(allAwards)
                ^ this                            ^ same as this
```

There's no reason to use a query result as the first parameter in `useQuery` in the first place -- this value should always be a DocumentNode object (which is what's returned when you use the `gql` tagged template). Maybe you have a naming conflict in there somewhere?

Comment: Epic face palm moment there Daniel. Thank you for taking the time to correct this lol